# <A>nchor Link to Local File? (<a href='file:///{path}'>DEAD LINK</a> not working in FireFox but in IE)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, file, firefox, anchor

This Java code,

```
"<a href='file:///" + curBP.get_build_path() + "'>" + curBP.get_build_path() + "</a>"
```

is outputted to the browser.

On the page, the HTML is:

```
<a href="file:///\\path\to\shared\file">Shared File</a>
```

However, it does not open the file. I've tried countless other combinations of slashes, but to no avail. In FireFox, it acts like a dead link and does not open the file. In IE, it works.

Any idea as to how to make it work in FireFox? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps because the web, unlike windows, uses *forward* slashes?

Comment: That doesn't apply to windows/local paths, does it. file:// expects a 'regular' file path.

Comment: @GolezTrol: When I view a local file on windows in firefox, the URL has forward slashes and everything works fine.

Comment: Could be. Might be a decision in the cross platform implementation. Doesn't matter after all, because Windows accepts forward slashes in file paths too. Still doesn't make sense. A local file is a local file, so it should follow local file naming conventions. There's no reason it should follow domain name conventions.

Comment: @GoeluTrol: First and foremost, it's an URI. An URI using the file protocol and therefore corresponding to a file path, but still an URI. And URIs use forward slashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bad news: Firefox has closed a security hole:

http://www.techlifeweb.com/firefox/2006/07/how-to-open-file-links-in-firefox-15.html

It requires the *user* to modify a local file to allow file:// urls.

Answer (score 1):

When you use backslashes {} , you're calling Windows Explorer. And IE is   integrated with Windows Explorer, FF not    integrated