# local link in HTML

Tags: html

This is HTML link to google:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

And it work fine

This is a link to my local file:

```
<a href="file:///C:/myhtml.html">Local</a>
```

And its not working, why?

If this is some sort of security issue, so how can I work around it? It's just for my own testing.

Comment: Its something wrong with permissions in the browser... its so the browser cant be used to attack your machine.

Comment: When you say "working", what file is this link in? Is it one that's on your local machine or one on a website?

Comment: @bouteillebleu on my local machine. if I copy path this link to my browser than it works just fine

Comment: You can work around it by saving this HTML file local and viewing it local, but it will never work from any domain other than file:////

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of link to a local file will work in some browsers as long as the HTML is also called from a local file. If not, it's a security vulnerability. It won't work at all in webkit based browsers.

See [<A>nchor Link to Local File? (<a href='file:///{path}'>DEAD LINK</a> not working in FireFox but in IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763863/anchor-link-to-local-file-a-href-file-pathdead-link-a-not-working)

And [Cross-browser link to file on local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254572/cross-browser-link-to-file-on-local-system)

Answer (score 0):

Due to Mozilla’s security model(as well as other modern browsers too), file://-links to local files on your computer or files on a network share do not work on (non-local) web pages; a click on such a link just does nothing. Links to local files could be useful on intranet sites like wikis.

There's an extension named LocalLink(http://locallink.mozdev.org/) for FireFox (and Thunderbird), that adds a new entry “Open Link in Local Context” to the link’s context menu. After you have installed the extension from https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/281 , you can open file://-links by right click on the link and select “Open Link in Local Context > Current Window”.