# Is there a way to open a file on the users local machine via JS/jQuery/asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here's the background -

The user enters the file path among other information. My application will display all the information back to the user. I need a way to display this file path as a link, such that the user can directly open this file by clicking on the link.

The file will reside on the users local machine.

What I've tried so far -

Adding the file path as a link ->

```
<a href="file:///H|\US\Connecticut\Stamford\Test\9.9 MB.doc">File to open</a>
```

However, nothing happens when i click on this link. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the pipe (`|`) instead of a colon (`:`) after your drive letter (H)?  Also, are you sure the file exists on the user's local machine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763863/anchor-link-to-local-file-a-href-file-pathdead-link-a-not-working