# Open image in a new window using Razor and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to open in a new window a new full size image from each one. I'm using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openImage(imageUrl) {
    window.open(imageUrl);
}
```

```
@foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
        <img src="@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Done", new { width = 150, height = 150, file = @imagen.filename })" alt="@imagen.filename" onclick="openImage('@Url.Content(ViewBag.Path + @imagen.filename)')" />
}
```

But using this when I click on a image it can't open anything.

Can you help me with this issue?

Thank you in advanced

EDITED the function openImage due to wrong code

Comment: Any errors in JS console?
Please debug what value of `imageUrl` comes to `openImage`.

Comment: BTW `imageUrl` argument and `imgUrl` in `window.open`. Is this cause of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to get the url of the directory which is saved the images in this way: `string url = Url.Content("~/Images");`

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of mismatched variable names in the question

```
imageUrl/imgUrl
image/@imagen
```

I'll assume these are typos for the question.

Could be that `ViewBag.Path` is missing a `/` at the end.  To get around this, don't concatenate (`+`) url parts, but use `System.IO.Path.Combine`, as in:

```
@Url.Content(Systemm.IO.Path.Combine(ViewBag.Path, image.filename))
```

Rather than using javascript `onclick`, you could change your loop to create simple links to new windows/tabs (these would also be navigable via the keyboard)

```
@foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
    <a target="_blank" href='@Url.Content(ViewBag.Path + @image.filename)'>
        <img src="@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Done", new { width = 150, height = 150 })" alt="@image.filename" />
    </a>
}
```

If this doesn't work (and I'm expecting it won't for you), please provide details for:

```
alert('@ViewBag.Path')

function openImage(imageUrl) {
    alert(imageUrl);
}
```

Comment: Doing the foreach code you put, images are displayed but when I click on them they don't open. The path is trying to open is something like this: file:///c:/users/xxx/documents/visual%20studio%202013/Projects/ProjectOne/ProjectFolder/Images/filename.jpg. The path exists, and when I copy and paste that path in a browser it is displayed, but in the normal runtime of the application it can't be opened.

Comment: That explains the bit of info you were missing `viewbag.path`.   The path should not be `file://` anything, it should be `http://yoursite/subpath/image`.  Can you confirm the value of `@ViewBag.Path' and the alert I suggested.

Comment: @ViewBag.Path is returning file:// format. In the controller I use this code to pass the viewbag to the view: ViewBag.Path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763863/anchor-link-to-local-file-a-href-file-pathdead-link-a-not-working